# paulirish/infinite-scroll is loading the wrong pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll No WordPress, just jQuery.

My links look like this

```
"mysite.com/whatever/25"
"mysite.com/whatever/50"
"mysite.com/whatever/75"
```

But it's loading new pages like this

```
"mysite.com/whatever/25"
"mysite.com/whatever/35"
"mysite.com/whatever/45"
```

Why won't it just use the href of the link I'm pointing it to `"#pagination li.active + li a"`? Instead of incrementing the part it thinks is the next page by 1!?

edit; I'm using offset numbers, not page numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try using this http://pengkong.github.io/jquery-auto-pagination/
it doesn't depend on running page numbers and/or fixed increments unlike infinite scroll.